# nginx proxy_pass on specific hostname only

Tags: nginx, web-server, proxypass

Suggesting i have two hostnames :

fr.xxx.com and 
de.xxx.com

I want that all call to /api from the hostname de.xxx.com are proxied to yy.xxx.com

I have tried this directive :

```
    if ($host ~ (^de.*)){
    set $doProxy 1;
    }

    if ($request_uri ~ (/api/*)){
    set $doProxy "${doProxy}2";
    }

    if ($doProxy = 12) {
    proxy_pass yy.xxx.com/api;
    }
```

But it does not work I am getting this error :

> nginx: [emerg] "proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by
>   regular expression, or inside named location, or inside "if"
>   statement, or inside "limit_except" block

Thank you for your help

Comment: None of your `if` blocks are necessary. The preferred way to do this is to move `de.xxx.com` into a separate `server` block.

Comment: It will cause a duplicated entry with my others servers